# package org.springframework.boot.test does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pom.xml

We are updating our spring boot from version to version 2.7.1

While building the code we are seeing  package org.springframework.boot.test does not exist error.

Below are the snippet of dependencies we have.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
</parent>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                 <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.2</version>
</dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.2</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
     <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

One of the file where we have contextconfiguration defined. We have couple of more with similar annotations.

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        ServicesConfig.class,
        RepositoryConfig.class,
        PropertySources.class,
        JmxConfig.class,
        UtilConfig.class,
        AsyncConfig.class,
        TenantIdentityConfig.class
})
@DirtiesContext
public abstract class AbstractAppInitializer {
}
```

Above are the dependencies I thought would be enough to have some analysis on. If any other information required, please let me know.

Update to Charlos. We already have spring-boot-starter-web defined in pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
             <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and remove the exclusions..

OR ...

You just need to check your Pom.xml and make sure your spring-boot-starter-data-jpa line is uncommented. You must have pring-boot-starter-data-jpa uncommented in your pom.xml file. If you dont have then just add it.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

it woks? tell me :-)

Comment: I have updated my question which also reflects the spring-boot-starter-web which we already have. Also why would we need jpa dependency? We do not have any relational database. We use mongo. Although I tried adding it but same errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the error message and the code, then we can see what's going on there.
I have got a same error, for me,

the compile error gives the line number which let me know the line:

`import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration` 
which requried by `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`
and check the doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.x/api/org/springframework/boot/test/SpringApplicationConfiguration.html, apparently it's deprecated.
So if you upgrade to a new version spring-boot and have new associated spring-boot-test dependency, this class is not there any longer.
You need to replace the annotation `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` with `@SpringBootTest`.
You can check it, and have a try.